# Finding the .Net framework

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to find out which .Net version i.e. 1.1 or 2.0 or 3.0 etc.. was used to create a web project. I have files like .aspx, .aspx.vb, web.config etc but need to figure that out.

Also how to open the existing ASP.Net project in Visual Studio environment. I have received files from another person but for security reasons he do not want to share the complete project but only selected files. We both would like to know what is the bare minimum files which needs to be shared to open an existing project (I mean apart from the .aspx, .aspx.vb files which needs to be modified)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

Open Visual Studio.

Click on File -> Open -> WebSite (Or press Alt+Shift+O).

Select the folder which containing your file (aspx, aspx.vb, web.config)

In most of the cases it will open the folder as web site and you can run it with F5.

Answer (score 1):

If its ASP.NET project check the <assemblies> element in web.config its must contain versions of each assembly you use.

Comment: It says assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0. KIndly let me know what it means

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the files you mentioned will contain any references to the version of .NET they were build under, not unless they feature version-specific code & functionality (LINQ for 3.0+. generics for 2.0+ etc).

In order to open an actual Web **project** in Visual Studio, you need the project file. Without that you will only be able to open individual files.