# Unable to open website in Visual studio any more

Tags: visual-studio

Pls refer

[Finding the .Net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021178/finding-the-net-framework)

Based on the inputs I was able to open the website using

**Click on File -> Open -> WebSite (Or press Alt+Shift+O).
Select the folder which containing your file (aspx, aspx.vb, web.config)**

It was all working fine till today morning.

Today morning, I presume there was some Silverlight installation or Windows update going on when I clicked to open the website and Visual Studio env went into hang state.

After that I have not been able to open the website from recent project list. I also tried renaming the directory and follow the approach i.e. Click on File -> Open -> WebSite (Or press Alt+Shift+O). but no success. The screen just blinks and cursor remains on the page showing latest news on Visual Studio

However my other websites are opening fine in Visual Studio env. If it helps I am using Visual Studio 2005

Request you to pls help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot open the website directly from the folder as I do not have complete website and that is precisely why I am following the approach of

Click on File -> Open -> WebSite (Or press Alt+Shift+O). Select the folder which containing your file (aspx, aspx.vb, web.config)

as suggested by someone earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer.

Try opening the WebSite directly from the folder, not in VS.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to try to open part of a web site.

Also, is there a chance that the original site was a web application project? It would have a .csproj or .vbproj file in it.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by resetting the export/import settings.
Romée